# How to create Swap from already created mount points

Tags: linux, centos, swap

I have prepared a CentOS 6.5 with all mount points at formatting time, including `swap`. Now, when I am trying to run command `swapon`, it shows `0 0 0`. And when I am trying to create it again using `mkswap`, it shows:

```
[root@01hw800724VM4 swap]# mkswap /dev/vg_01hw800724vm4/swap
/dev/vg_01hw800724vm4/swap: Device or resource busy
```

Please help.
`swapon -s` result

```
[root@01hw800724VM4 ~]# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
```

`df` result:

```
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-root   1032088  1015700         0 100% /
tmpfs                               7973632       72   7973560   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-admin             118997     5648    107205   6% /admin
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-backup         206424760 20226912 175712088  11% /backup
/dev/vda3                            495844    39722    430522   9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-cdcopy          92891128   188104  87984432   1% /cdcopy
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-home             2064208    92140   1867212   5% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-sapmnt_EAH      15481840  1387252  13308156  10% /sapmnt/EAH
/dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap  30965628   176048  29221764   1% /swap
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-tmp              7224824  3654996   3202892  54% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-usr             58831036  2760256  53082340   5% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-EAH              9289080  2869132   5948092  33% /usr/sap/EAH
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-trans           41284928   180160  39007616   1% /usr/sap/trans
/dev/mapper/vg_vm4-var              2064208   386668   1572684  20% /var
```

Comment: What does your `swapon -s` give? And what is your `pwd`? Also please do a `df` and paste

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you're getting the `Device or resource busy` error is because the device that you're trying to create the swap on is already mounted.

You can see that in your `mount` output:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap  30965628   176048  29221764   1% /swap
```

Swap is not mounted on a mountpoint (you won't see it in the output of `mount`). To fix the issue, you need to do the following:

1. Remove the entry in `/etc/fstab` that mounts that filesystem on `/swap`.
2. Umount `/swap`.

   ```
   umount /swap
   ```
3. Initialiase your swap device and start using it. This will **erase** whatever is currently on `/dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap`.

   ```
   mkswap /dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap
   swapon /dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap
   ```
4. Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to mount it as swap on boot:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/vg_01hw800724vm4-swap    none   swap    sw    0    0
   ```

That should be all you need to do.

Comment: thanks for solution but i deleted that mount point removed entry from f stab and then recreated. and now it showing swapon. but it not showing free 30 gb which i had deleted mount point.

Comment: If you've used that filesystem for swap, you're not going to see the space as free filesystem space - you'll see it as available swap (try the `free` command)